# How to access a subDocumet of subDocument using DBObject

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I need to get a list of all the name fields from the following json.  I'm trying to do this by mapping a DBObject.

JSON:

```
{
    "firstOne": [
        {
            "file": "FileA",
            "Data": "One",
            "version": "0.4"
        }
    ],
    "secondOne": [
        {
            "elementName": "version",
            "complexElement": "true",
            "elementDataType": ""
        }
    ],
    "ThirdOne": [
        {
            "elementName": "version",
            "explicitElements": [
                {
                    "name": "mytag",
                    "type": "String",
                    "value": "myrequest"
                },
                {
                    "name": "booleantest",
                    "type": "Boolean",
                    "value": "true"
                }
            ]
        }
    ] }
```

CODE:

> DBCollection collection = mongoTemplate.getCollection("testTag");
>
> ```
>   Map<DBObject, DBObject> map = new HashMap<DBObject, DBObject>();
>   DBObject obj =null;
>
>   BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
>   query.put("ThirdOne.explicitElements.name", "myTag");
>   BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject();
>   fields.put("ThirdOne.explicitElements.name", 1);
>   fields.put("ThirdOne.explicitElements.value", 1);
>
>   DBCursor cursor2 = collection.find(query, fields);      while
> ```
>
> (cursor2.hasNext()) {             obj = cursor2.next();           map = obj.toMap();
>
> ```
>       for (Map.Entry<DBObject, DBObject> entry : map.entrySet()) {
>           System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() + " Value : "
>                   + entry.getValue());
>
>
>       }
>               }
> ```

RESULTS:

> key: _id Value: 523f910681a9535f8af5aa91
>
> Key: ThirdOne Value: [{ "explicitElements" : [{"name":"mytag",
>   "value":"myrequest"},{"name":"booleantest", "value":"true"}]}]

I would like to get only

> key: "name"  value: "mytag"
>
> key: "value"   value: "myrequest"  etc...

Any suggestions on how to do this using DBObjects?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using arrays with just a single object in them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have here is a bunch of value-fields stored in `DBObject`s stored in `DBList`s stored in `DBObject`s stored in `DBList`s stored in `DBObject`s iterated by a `DBCursor`. Due to this convoluted document-structure you need to walk through this whole tree when you want to output only those on a specific leaf of it.

```
while (cursor2.hasNext()) {
     // you are now iterating a list objects with three Fields:
     // FirstOne, SecondOne and ThirdOne. You only want ThirdOne
     obj = cursor2.next();
     map = obj.toMap();
     DBList thirdOne = (DBList)map.get("ThirdOne");
     // now we iterat the list in ThirdOne
     for (Object o: thirdOne) {
           DBObject thirdOneEntry = (DBObject)o;     
           // we get the explicitElements-array from each entry    
           DBList explicitElements = (DBList)thirdOneEntry.get("explicitElements");
           // now we iterate the expliciteElements         
           for (Object o: explicitElements) { 
               DBObject explicitElementsEntry = (DBObject)o;
               // and write them
               Object key = explicitElementsEntry.get("key");
               Object value = explicitElementsEntry.get("value");
               System.out.println("Key : " + key.toString() + " Value : " value.toString());
           }
     }
}
```

Comment: I tried the code by i get the error below when doing a maven clean install.  The error is on the line : for (DBObject thirdOneEntry: thirdOne) .     ERROR:   :  incompatible types
[ERROR] found   : java.lang.Object
[ERROR] required: com.mongodb.DBObject

Comment: I updated my answer. This should do it, but I can't test it right now.

Comment: Thank you this worked.  I just had to change how the key/value were being printed because i was getting a null exception after the first key/value pair printed.  I used the following instead:     map2=explicitElementsEntry.toMap();
              for (Map.Entry<DBObject, DBObject> entry : map2.entrySet()) {
         System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() + " Value : "
           + entry.getValue());
        }